# Does animateLayoutChanges work on ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

a listView is a ViewGroup and seems like a good candidate for having animated layout changes. However, it seems to disregard the flag or constructing a LayoutTransition manually and setting it up that way. What gives? It's not documented anywhere that this very important ViewGroup doesn't support this very import animation feature.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no, the `ListView` doesn't support `android:animateLayoutChanges`, at least not in the way you expect it to. It'll just animate the children the `ListView` has to create when it can't reuse an existing view.

Answer (score 1):

I add that using the option android:animateLayoutChanges="true" in the layout of the ListView prevents you from selecting any item of the ListView; you can do that, only after doing something like adding a new item and returning to the ListView.
I have experienced this bug using the SimpleCursorAdapter up-to-date and the one that comes with  v4 support library

Regards
FD